# D3, Typescript - Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I have stackbiltz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/lable-line-break-vaszab?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I have a d3 bar chart in and Angular app.

The x axis labels are split onto two lines using a function that is called as the z axis ticks are created

```
private insertLinebreak(d) {

    let labels = d3.select(this);
    let words = d;
    console.log("Label:", labels.html());
    labels.text('');

    let index = words.indexOf(' ', words.indexOf(' ') + 1)
    let title = words.substr(0, index)
    let subtitle = words.substr(index + 1)

    let tspantitle = labels.append('tspan').text(title)
    let tspansubtitle = labels.append('tspan').text(subtitle)
    tspantitle
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('dy', '15')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis-title');
    tspansubtitle
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('dy', '16')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis-subtitle');

  };
```

The function uses 'this' to select the 'g' calling the function (but in d3 I think it selects the whole svg)

This code works in stackblitz but in my actual code I get the error

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BaseType'.
```

I know this isn't very helpful

I think this hasbto do with Typescript and the way it handles 'this'

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this.

Comment: This sounds like a *type* error related to TypeScript, and D3 isn't a TypeScript library. You can install type support by adding `npm install @types/d3 --save` to your project. `BaseType` is part of the D3 types and you can look at the `.d.ts` files from the mentioned package to see what the typed signature of `d3.select` is. You'll need to cast `this` to that type, but that doesn't mean your code is functionally. This is just a typing error from TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was related to Typescript. I have d3 types installed in the app. The actual app works but this error means I cant push it to production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler infers the type of `this` inside your `insertLinebreak()` function as your class `StackedChartCompoent`. Looking at the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/444ae0e62284ed7f070c0bf563a2a9ca7fe5e2e5/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L123) for `d3.select(node)`, however, you can see that it expects the node to extend `BaseType` which is [defined](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/444ae0e62284ed7f070c0bf563a2a9ca7fe5e2e5/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L21) as

```
export type BaseType = Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | null;
```

Because your class clearly does not extend this `BaseType` you got the error.

There are basically two ways around this:

1. If you need the `insertLinebreak()` method only at one place, namely as the callback to `.each()`, you can make it a function expression which is then passed directly as an argument to `.each()`

   ```
   .each(function() {
     let labels = d3.select(this);   // works
     // ...the original method's body
   })
   ```

   This works because the compiler now knows the single entry point for this function and can infer the type of `this` since [`.each()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/9ffa69f363b5ee9af2171879d798091eab68def0/src/selection/each.js#L5) uses [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to bind `this` to the node.

   <sub>Keep in mind, though, that you have to use the classic function expression in favor of an ES6 arrow function because that would have `this` again point to its lexical scope instead of to the node.</sub>
2. Fortunately, there is a more idiomatic way built into TypeScript itself. Since [version 2.0](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions) you can provide a fake [`this` parameter](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) as the first item in your function's parameter list. This parameter tells the compiler what `this` is referring to inside of said function. Your code could thus be rewritten as:

   ```
   private insertLinebreak(this: SVGTextElement) {
     let labels = d3.select(this);   // works
     // method body left untouched
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If still someone cannot find a solution, give this a try !!!

```
private insertLinebreak(d,i,n){
  //d is your data
  //i is the current index
  //n is the current node
  let labels = d3.select(this); // won't work
  let labels = d3.select(n[i]); // works
 }
```

Happy coding !!!!